# There are 189 questions tagged [belongs-on-superuser] on Server Fault

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

**Update 7th June 2010**

These are all gone on Stack Overflow and Super User. ServerFault is a different story:

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-superuser - 189 questions

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-stackoverflow - 14 questions

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-meta - 0 questions

---

**Update 9th June 2010**

Stack Overflow links for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-serverfault - 0 questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-superuser - 0 questions.

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-meta - 0 questions.

---

Super User links for reference:

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-serverfault - 0 questions.

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-stackoverflow - 0 questions

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/belongs-on-meta - 0 questions.

Unfortunately the quick retagging exploit for closed questions no longer works.

Comment: Would those tags be candidates for the planned tag black list? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list

Comment: @Troggy - indeed they would.

Comment: Troggy, these tags are the reason why this list was suggested.

Comment: Yes, ignore my question mark. Look, a badger!

Comment: There are no "belongs-on-superuser" questions on stack overflow because everyone on stack overflow appears to punt *anything* that doesn't belong there to serverfault, even if it's obviously a superuser question...

Comment: Noooo! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765365/format-usb-flash-drive-8gb-to-be-bootable-closed got migrated to SU with the tag intact, so unless a moderator sees and has mercy we're stuck with a permanent belongs-on-superuser question.

Comment: Um, I'm completely stunned to learn that belongs-on* is evil. I saw them, and when I got points to retag,  I started to use them, and I've never seen anything to indicate that I was trangressing. More propaganda needed?

Comment: @bmargulies - it's one of the "unwritten" rules rather than being something in the faq for example. It's come up here on meta quite a few times. The problem is that these tags are just noise especially when they get left on questions that have been migrated.

Comment: @bmargulies: I had the same problem. I've seen this "belongs-to-*" and since I don't regularly reads all meta feature requests/modifications I didn't know it's being "deprecated". I would like to have an "Advanced FAQ" that can address all these hidden rules of SO. I thought I was just being good for the community and now people say it's evil.

Comment: Yesterday and today someone went in and tagged some questions belongs-on-doctype. This tag is even more abominable in my opinion because questions cannot be migrated to doctype, nor is there a clear line between what's acceptable on SO and what belongs on doctype.

Comment: I got 407 problems, but a tag ain't one.

Comment: excellent, thanks for cleaning this up!

Comment: When a question is moved from stack overflow to server fault, is it normal that the associated answers are marked as deleted?
Or was that only because (at the time) I had only ever logged in to stack overflow, never to server fault?

Comment: It is unfortunate that I cannot do anything to clean up serverfault given that the vast majority of these questions are closed.

Comment: @DouglasDD - yes it's normal that answers are deleted from the original question.

Comment: @Zoredache - When the quick tag editing was introduced you could edit the tags on closed questions, which is how I was able to remove the tags from Stack Overflow. I couldn't do Server Fault as I don't have enough rep. However, that feature was removed so now only very few people can remove those tags now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying to clean up a bunch of the belongs-on tags, but eventually gave up (except for new questions I see which have them). It really grinds my gears, because many of them get closed & migrated (hence locked) before the tag gets removed.

People, please, if you're voting to close a question which has one of the abominable tags on it, please, please, please remove the tag first. :)

And once again, I would be totally in favor of a tag blacklist containing anything that even starts with "belongs-on" ... (That should be easier than specifically blacklisting individually, just blacklist anything that starts with the word "belong". Done!)

Comment: +1 for removing the tag when voting

Comment: I always remove the tag when someone adds it to a question. Doesn't stop that person from retagging it back. You'd think people would be capable of getting the hint.

Comment: @Brandon: That kind of thing makes me wish there were a way, over TCP/IP, to smack 'em with a sock full o' nickels ... (Yes, I'm kidding, but sadly you're right, some people just don't get the hint.)

Comment: @Brandon - I've started adding a comment - well two actually. The first to the owner to head on over to the other site and set up an account and the second to tell everyone else not to add the "belongs-on" tag back.

Comment: +1 "... grinds my gears"

Comment: @ChrisF, I've started telling people to stop retagging it, however I don't usually tell the OP to head over to the other site. I use to, but then I began to realize that if it was taking too long to gain 5 votes, the OP would just go ask the question on the other site rather than waiting for it to be migrated.

Comment: I usually put an edit reason of "belongs-on-* is not a valid tag". On the other hand, adding that tag to an old question might be the only way a low-rep user can draw attention to it - except for flagging for moderator attention, of course.

Comment: Ah, but flagging for mod attention is the correct way to do that.

Comment: these tags get automatically removed when migration occurs.. FYI. Anything beginning with "belongs-on-"

Comment: @Jeff - but the tag is remaining on old posts which is cluttering up the site.

Comment: @Cigars: I look forward to your RFC proposal for an SfoNoIP protocol.

Comment: @womble: That **so** makes two of us! I wonder if I can at least send the `printer_on_fire` message remotely. Ahhh, but to dream ...

Comment: I'm going to write a language called belongs-on just to make that a valid tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, if they belong on serverfault then they should have the tag.  This way someone like yourself can look them all up at once.  It adds to the organizational capabilities of the site as tags should.

Comment: I really can't tell if you're being facetious or not.

Comment: Add a comment or if it's really desperate flag the post. I can't speak for anyone else but I can often tell if a question belongs on one of the other sites from it's title.

Comment: Hmm, hiding behind that wiki blanket again are we?

Comment: I think I have an answer on facetiousness ... Well Lance, I'd say we should agree to disagree, but the powers that be have already come down against using `[belongs-on*]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/so-it-is-written-so-it-shall-be/4211#4211

Comment: The other thing you (as a < 3000 rep user) can do is add a comment with a link to the duplicate. This will get picked up and used.

Comment: @ChrisF, I use all the options: migrate, comment and tag.

Comment: But tag is not a valid option, according to the site's management. Thus, it should not be done. It creates noise and garbage. The only people who search for those tags are people like me, who occasionally want to go on a cleanup binge, and even I've given up on it because 90% of the questions with the tags are already migrated. Bottom line: **don't do it.** Migrate, comment, and flag if needed, but leave `[belongs-on-*]` out of it.

Comment: After the question is closed and moved, it no longer belongs on the site at all. It is doomed to oblivion after it falls of the front page, except to mods and pseudo-mods. There is no reason for it to be organized or tagged at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is now sorted.

I've now got enough rep to retag and did the last few today alongside Kara Marfia (purely coincidentally).

Comment: coincidentally, sure.